# Introduce a topology on a countable space (such az N) with the following feature.

Tags: general-topology

Introduce a Hausdorff  topology on a countable space (such as $\mathbb{N}$) that no member of this space is an open set.please give me an example on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Members of the space can never be open sets, since they are not subsets of that space. Did you mean no singleton is open?

Comment: I mean there are no open set (including x) such that there is no member in that open set except x

Comment: @Adayah: Well, if using $\mathbb N=\omega$, then indeed *every* member is also a subset. Although I'm pretty sure that's not what ebad meant. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a bijection $f$ from countable set $X$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ and define $O$ to be open in $X$ iff $f[O]$ is open in the rationals (usual topology from its metric or equivalently its order)

Comment: thank you very much . you did it.